# What does Peer dl. mean in bittorrent?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I'm seeding a torrent file in bittorrent, and under Peers tab it shows a column called Peer dl. What does that mean and what do the numbers in the column mean?

Answer (score 2):

It is the *estimated* rate at which the Peer is downloading this particular Torrent ([Ref](http://www.bittorrent.com/help/manual/appendixa010503#Peer_Download_Rate)),

> Peer Download Rate is an estimated rate at which the peer is
>   downloading based on the peer's reported change in pieces obtained.
>   This estimation is very crude and is most likely inaccurate, so it
>   should only be lightly relied upon.